# How can Revoke an existing Trustline of an Asset for a specific Account?

Tags: assets, trustline, anchor, python-sdk

I'm a bit confused about how can an Anchor, Revoke an existing Trustline of an Asset for a specific Account?
I'm using https://github.com/StellarCN/py-stellar-base, so it supposed to be done by submitting a Transaction with an append_change_trust_op() call, signed by Asset's Issuer/Trustee Account, but this method has no parameter to specify what Trustor/Consumer Account I want to be as the target!
P.S.
The authorization_required and authorization_revocable flags of Issuer Account are set to True, authorization_immutable = False.
The target Account has already an Authorized Trustline to the Asset.

Comment: I figured it out! The "change trust" operation, excutes by "trustors" to create/update/delete "trustline", then "trustees" use "allow trust" to Authorize/deAuthorize line(s) already established to them. that's all.

Comment: Are you a member of our public Keybase team? If not, it's a good place to find other developers and ask questions. You can join here: https://keybase.io/team/stellar.public